# Top Navigation Created with Bootstrap Does not Collapse the Sub Menus

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have created a top navigation with a Navbar Header, 4 main links one with a drop down submenu and the caret.

The drop down submenu is not collapsing. I have tried to find the issue but couldn't find it. Please refer the below code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap with HTML</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar with Dropdown Menus -->
  <!-- Start Navbar Top -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Toggle buttons snippet -  This will define the toggle buttons of the navigation when the screen gets smaller -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- End of Toggle button snippet -->

      <!-- The Site Name or Brand name snippet -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="www.youtube.com" target="_blank">The Bootstrap Site with HTML</a>
      <!-- End of brand name snippet -->

      <!-- The below defines the navigation links in the Navbar. From this point you can create the links for the navigation -->
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Technologies</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="drop-down">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">SaaS</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">PaaS</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Cloud</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">IofT</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--End of the navigation links in the Navbar -->

    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End of Navbar Top -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its working for me on chrome 52. which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-toggle="drop-down"` should be`data-toggle="dropdown"` and it all works fine now.

Check it out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap with HTML</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar with Dropdown Menus -->
  <!-- Start Navbar Top -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Toggle buttons snippet -  This will define the toggle buttons of the navigation when the screen gets smaller -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- End of Toggle button snippet -->

      <!-- The Site Name or Brand name snippet -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="www.youtube.com" target="_blank">The Bootstrap Site with HTML</a>
      <!-- End of brand name snippet -->

      <!-- The below defines the navigation links in the Navbar. From this point you can create the links for the navigation -->
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Technologies</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">SaaS</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">PaaS</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Cloud</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">IofT</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--End of the navigation links in the Navbar -->

    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End of Navbar Top -->


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap with HTML</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
      <!-- Navbar with Dropdown Menus -->
         <!-- Start Navbar Top -->
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container">
              <!-- Toggle buttons snippet -  This will define the toggle buttons of the navigation when the screen gets smaller -->
             <div class="navbar-header">
             
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
             
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="www.youtube.com" target="_blank">The Bootstrap Site with HTML</a>
             </div>
             <!-- End of Toggle button snippet -->

              <!-- The Site Name or Brand name snippet -->
               <!-- End of brand name snippet -->

                <!-- The below defines the navigation links in the Navbar. From this point you can create the links for the navigation -->
                 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li ><a href="#">Technologies</a></li>
                      <li ><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li><a href="#">SaaS</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">PaaS</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Cloud</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">IofT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
                <!--End of the navigation links in the Navbar -->

              </div>
          </nav>
            <!-- End of Navbar Top -->



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="drop-down">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

for this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
```